# Rebound allocator initialization in std::list

Tags: c++, list, oop, stl, allocator

I am trying to implement std::list (circle trick) with a custom allocator, but I've faced a problem while trying to code a constructor. My current code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T> >
class List {
private:
    struct BaseNode {
        BaseNode* prev = this;
        BaseNode* next = this;
    };

    struct Node : BaseNode {
        T value;
    };

    using AllocNode = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<Node>;
    using AllocTraits = std::allocator_traits<AllocNode>;

    BaseNode fake_base;
    size_t sz = 0;
    AllocNode alloc_node;

public:
    explicit List(const Alloc& alloc = Alloc())
        : alloc_node(AllocNode())
    {
    }

    ~List()
    {
        BaseNode *cur_node = fake_base.next, *next_node;
        while (cur_node != &fake_base) {
            next_node = cur_node->next;
            AllocTraits::deallocate(alloc_node, (Node*)cur_node, 1);
            cur_node = next_node;
        }
    }
};
```

I am rebinding Allocator in order to store an instance of Allocator. However, I do not know how to use the variable alloc of type Allocator in the constructor and initialize alloc_node with a default value:

```
explicit List (const Alloc& alloc = Alloc()) : alloc_node(AllocNode()) {}
```

Are there any ways to construct alloc_node via alloc? Otherwise why do I need alloc at all?

Comment: You can automatically format your code with clang-format, there's even an online service: http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the allocator, `std::allocator` is stateless so it's [constructors have no visible effect](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocator). I'd imagine a custom allocator might be constructed via `alloc_node(alloc)`

Comment: @AlanBirtles The compiler does not generate any errors if I do `alloc_node(alloc)`. I wonder why that is the case, since my Allocator has a custom argument Node

Comment: Difficult to know without seeing your allocator

Comment: It is in fact required (Table 31 in **[allocator.requirements]**) that `X u(b);` compile, where `X` is an allocator type for some type `T` and `b` is of an allocator type `Y` that's the result of rebinding `X` for some type `U`. Moreover, after this statement it should be the case that `Y(u) == b` and `u == X(b)` (that is, converting back to the original allocator type must produce an equivalent allocator). So therefore, `alloc_node(alloc)` is the right thing to do, and your custom allocator must support that, in order to meet allocator requirements.

Comment: @AmirMokhammed-Ali, it is advisable to call `AllocTraits::destroy()` before deallocating the node (destroy-deallocate process).